# Remove single marker with phonegap and google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using phonegape, google maps api v3 and navigator.geolocation.watchPosition function in my project.

I try to follow my position. I have problem with markers. Application working good, but doesn't remove old markers. It creates new markers all time, when i will get new coords.

```
    function onSuccess(position) {

    var image = 'arrow1.png';

             var pos_table = ['Here I am', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
             var where_i_am = new google.maps.LatLng(pos_table[1], pos_table[2]);
             var my_position = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: where_i_am,
                 map: map,
                 title: pos_table[0],
                 icon: image
             });

             map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
                    position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude
                ));

    }
```

I added setmap(null), but now there aren't any markers on the map

```
 for (var i = 0; i < my_position.length; i++) {
    my_position[i].setMap(null);
 }
```

When I try :

```
if (my_position) {
    for (var i = 0; i < my_position.length; i++) {
        my_position[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

it dosen't work at all. Please help me. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to delete old markers, you could try to use update the position of the old marker.

```
var my_position;
function onSuccess(position) {

    var image = 'arrow1.png';
    var pos_table = ['Here I am', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
    var where_i_am = new google.maps.LatLng(pos_table[1], pos_table[2]);
    if (my_position) {
        my_position.setPosition(where_i_am);
    } else {
        my_position = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: where_i_am,
            map: map,
            title: pos_table[0],
            icon: image
        });

    }

    map.panTo(where_i_am);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
 var my_position = new Array();
 function onSuccess(position) {
for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    var image = 'arrow1.png';

             var pos_table = ['Here I am', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
             var where_i_am = new google.maps.LatLng(pos_table[1], pos_table[2]);
             my_position[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: where_i_am,
                 map: map,
                 title: pos_table[0],
                 icon: image
             });

             map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
                    position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude
                ));

    }
}
```